# perl seek and remove at varying offsets in binmode

Tags: perl, seek, vary

This is my script I am writing.

```
#usr/bin/perl
use warnings;


open(my $infile, '<', "./file1.bin") or die "Cannot open file1.bin: $!";
binmode($infile);
open(my $outfile, '>', "./extracted data without 00's.bin") or die "Cannot create extracted data without 00's.bin: $!";
binmode($outfile);

local $/; $infile = <STDIN>;
   print substr($infile, 0, 0x840, '');
   $infile =~ s/\0{16}//;
   print $outfile;
```

I'm loading a binary file in perl.
I have been able to seek and patch at certain offsets, but what I would like to do is, now be able to find any instance of "`00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`" (16 bytes?) and remove it from the file, but no less than 16 bytes. Anything less than that I would want to leave. In some of the files the offset where the 00's start will be at different offsets, but if I am thinking correctly, if I can just search for `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` and remove any instance of it, then it won't matter what offset the 00's are at. I would extract the data first from specific offsets, then search the file and prune 00's from it. I can already extract the specific offsets I need, I just need to open the extracted file and shave off `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00`

```
EF 39 77 5B 14 9D E9 1E 94 A9 97 F2 6D E3 68 05
6F 7B 77 BB C4 99 67 B5 C9 71 12 30 9D ED 31 B6 
AB 1F 81 66 E1 DD 29 4E 71 8D 54 F5 6C C8 86 0D 
5B 72 AF A8 1F 26 DD 05 AF 78 13 EF A5 E0 76 BB 
8A 59 9B 20 C5 58 95 7C E0 DB 44 6A EC 7E D0 10 
09 42 B1 12 65 80 B3 EC 58 1A 2F 92 B9 32 D9 07 
96 DE 32 51 4B 5F 3B 50 9A D1 09 37 F4 6D 7C 01 
01 4A A4 24 04 DC 83 08 17 CB 34 2C E5 87 26 C1 
35 38 F4 C4 E4 78 FE FC A2 BE 99 48 C9 CA 69 90 
33 87 09 A8 27 BA 91 FC 4B 77 FA AB F5 1E 4E C0        I want to leave everything from
F2 78 6E 31 7D 16 3B 53 04 8A C1 A8 4B 70 39 22 <----- here up
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 <----- I want to prune everything
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00        from here on
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00<---- this IS the end of the file, and
                                                     just need to prune these few rows
                                                     of 00's
```

Say that "`F2 78 6E`" from the example above, is at offset `0x45000` **BUT** in another file the 00 00's will start at a different offset, how could I code it so the `00 00's` would get pruned. In any file that I am opening?
If I need to be more specific, just ask.
Seems like I would peekk so far into the file until I hit a long 00 00 string, then prune any remaining lines. Does that make sense at all?
All I want to do is search the file for any instances of `00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00` and delete/prune/truncate it. I want to save everything but the 00's

**EDIT #2**
this did it:

```
open($infile, '<', './file1') or die "cannot open file1: $!";
binmode $infile;
open($outfile, '>', './file2') or die "cannot open file2: $!";
binmode $outfile;

local $/; $file = <$infile>;
$file =~ s/\0{16}//g;
print $outfile $file;


close ($infile);
close ($outfile);
```

**Thank you `ikegami` for all your help and patience :)**

Comment: You opened `$infile`, but read from `STDIN`. You overwrite your file handle with the content of the file. (Goes to show your variable names are substandard. Use `..._fh` for file handles.) You didn't say what to print.

Comment: trust me i been giving it a good go man. i think i am gonna give up tonight and do some more tomorrow. thanks for all your help so far. but to make myself clear, all i wanna do is open the extracted 59kn file, and delete the few rows of 00;s off the end lol. sounds easy enough. i can open HxD and do it manually, but a nice script to just double click makes it alot easier for me. i work with these files daily and have to manually check them, and it would be nice to have a tool that seperated each part of the file, the 59kb file is just part of a 16MB file. but alot of the other data is static,

Comment: and i dont have any trouble at all extracting that, and what i am doing is extracting a little more than 59 kb, that way every file will be padded at the end with 00's, then i want to add this script to delete them 00's. anyways, thanks for all yoru help so far man.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No such thing as removing from a file. You have to either

1. copy the file without the undesired bits, or
2. `read` the rest of the file, `seek` back, `print` over the undesired bits, then `truncate` the file.

I went with option 1.

```
$ perl -e'
   binmode STDIN;
   binmode STDOUT;
   local $/; $file = <STDIN>;
   $file =~ s/\0{16}//;
   print $file;
' <file.in >file.out
```

I'm loading the entire file into memory. Either option can be done in chunks, but it complicates things because your NULs could span two chunks.

---

In a poorly phrased update, you seem to have asked to avoid changes in the first 0x840 bytes. Two solutions:

```
$ perl -e'
   binmode STDIN;
   binmode STDOUT;
   local $/; $file = <STDIN>;
   substr($file, 0x840) =~ s/\0{16}//;
   print $file;
' <file.in >file.out

$ perl -e'
   binmode STDIN;
   binmode STDOUT;
   local $/; $file = <STDIN>;
   print substr($file, 0, 0x840, '');
   $file =~ s/\0{16}//;
   print $file;
' <file.in >file.out
```

Comment: You should have told me why my solution wasn't good enough. I only noticed your update as a fluke.

Comment: original post updated. when i run this, it tried to run, but hangs with a blinking cursor.

Comment: please have patience with me, this is a learning experience for me. i can program, but i am not intermediate man, so please have patience ;) im learning, lol

Comment: might i add this file is only 59kb

Comment: the variable offsets dont vary no more than a few kb from file to file. is there not a way i could load a hex string say for instance **/0x00, /0x00, /0x00, /0x00,/0x00, /0x00, /0x00, /0x00,/0x00, /0x00, /0x00, /0x00,/0x00, /0x00, /0x00, /0x00** into a variable, then search and remove any exact instances of that exact variable? then i could just extract the section i want, and simply delete the 00 hex strings off the end of it, which isnt but 4 or 5 lines of hex string

Comment: Sure, change `$file =~ s/\0{16}//;` to `$str = "\0" x 16; $file =~ s/\Q$str//;`

Comment: ok i got it sort of working m8, but it only deletes one line of zero's

Comment: i setup a test file with 5 lines of 00's in a hex file named "file1" when i run it thru the cose, it deletes one line of the 00's.

Comment: i just need it to recursively search again and again until it cant find any instance of "00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00"

Comment: by the way, thanks for your help so far man, it is really appreciated. also its the first option that i got working, just need it to search over and over. would i use a loop of a sort?

Comment: oh, you want to delete all instances of 16 NULs? Add the "g" flag to the substitution, `s/\0{16}//g`.

Comment: dont kill me, but how would i strip "FF" the same way? i tried to input "$file =~ s/\F{16}//g; but it does nothing.